# Qt QTextDocument new line?

Tags: c++, qt

Good day, the problem is simple: I can't get a new line in the QTextDocument when using the setHtml() method. My input is:

```
"<i>Hello</i> <b>World</b> </br> a"
```

and my output is:

*Hello* **World** a

Which means that the italics and bold text are alright, but the `'a'` should be in a new line.

I will post the entire source code below. There are a coupple of things to note:

1) The QTextDocument is then transmited to a QPrinter so it can create a PDF file with the text.

2) If you are going to test the program you should change line 15

```
printer.setOutputFileName("C:\\Users\\SameTime\\Desktop\\2.pdf");
```

To a path which is suitable for you.

The source code:

```
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QString>
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{

    QApplication app( argc, argv );
     QPrinter printer;
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.A4;
   QTextDocument doc;
   QString a ="<i>Hello</i> <b>World</b> </br> a";
   doc.setHtml(a);
   printer.setOutputFileName("C:\\Users\\SameTime\\Desktop\\2.pdf");
   doc.print(&printer);
   printer.newPage();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<br>`. `</br>` is invalid.

```
<i>Hello</i> <b>World</b> <br> a
```

Comment: Works, thank you. I will mark this as an answer when the 15 minute timer expires.

Answer (score 2):

Riateche is *almost* right.

While `</br>` is invalid in any HTML version, the "proper" form for some HTML versions (esp: xhtml) is actually `<br/>` although many browsers will cope with `<br>` just fine.

Comment: You are also _almost_ right. The "proper" form is always `<br>` for HTML and `<br />` for XHTML. In XHTML pages, browsers won't be able to cope with `<br>`.